# Which attributes should be used for right assotiation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using entity framework and have some classes

```
public class Lot
{
    public int LotId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser CurrentCustomer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> AllCustomers { get; set; }
    public virtual AuctionDates AuctionDates { get; set; }
    public  virtual AuctionPrices AuctionPrices { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductImages Images { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lot> SelledLots { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lot> BuyedLots { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Lot> ParticipatedLots { get; set; }
}
```

And the question is how can I set configuration for mapped user who Sell Lot(ApplicationUser) in Owner(Lot), who buy lot(ApplicationUser) in current customer(Lot) and so on. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found the  answer. In this situation data annotation InverseProperty should be used.  https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s03.html

```
public class Lot
{
    public int LotId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SelledLots")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("BuyedLots")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser CurrentCustomer { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ParticipatedLots")]
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> AllCustomers { get; set; }
    public virtual AuctionDates AuctionDates { get; set; }
    public  virtual AuctionPrices AuctionPrices { get; set; }
    public virtual State State { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductImages Images { get; set; }
}
```